#  Select capitalized & all-caps words using RegEx

Tags: regex

I'm trying to find names of people and companies (everything that is capitalized but not in the beginning of a sentence) in a large body of text. The purpose is to find as many instances as possible so that they can be XML-tagged properly.

This is what I've come up with so far:

`[^\W](\s\b[\p{Lu}][\p{Lu}|\p{Ll}]+\b)+`

It has two problems:

1. It selects two characters too many in front of the hit. 
   In the sentence *"Is this Beetle ugly?"* it finds **s Beetle** which complicates the subsequent tagging.
2. When a capitalized word is preceded with an apostrophe or a colon, it isn't found. If possible I'd like to limit what characters are used for determining a sentence to just **!?.**

Here's the sample text I'm using to test it out:

> John Adams is my hero. There's just no limits to his imagination!  Is
>   this Beetle ugly? It sings at the: La Scala opera house. I have a
>   dream that I will find work at' Frame Store but not in the USA! This
>   way ILM could do whatever they pleased. ILM was very sweet. Visual
>   Effects did a good job... Neither did Animatronix?

I'm using jEdit http.//jedit.org since I need something that works on both Windows and OS X.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update, this avoids now the matching at the start of the string.

```
(?<!(?:[!?\.]\s|^))(\b[\p{Lu}][\p{Lu}\p{Ll}]+\b)+
```

`(?<!(?:[!?\.]\s|^))` is a negative lookbehind that ensures it is not preceded by one of the  `!?.` and a space OR by the start of a new row.

I tested it with jEdit.

Update to cover Names consisting of multiple words

```
(?<!(?:[!?\.]\s|^))(\b[\p{Lu}][\p{Lu}\p{Ll}]*\b(?:\s\b[\p{Lu}][\p{Lu}\p{Ll}]*\b)*)+
                                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ (added)
                                            ^ (changed)
```

I added the group `(?:\s\b[\p{Lu}][\p{Lu}\p{Ll}]*\b)*` to match optional following words starting with uppercase letters. And I changed the `+` to a `*` to match the `A` in your example `My company's called A Few Good Men`. But this change causes now the regex to match `I` as a name.

See tchrists comment. Names are not a simple thing and it gets really difficult if you want to cover the more complex cases.

This is also working

```
(?<!\p{P}\s)(\b[\p{Lu}][\p{Lu}|\p{Ll}]+\b)+
```

But `\p{P}` covers all punctuation, I understood this is not what you want. But maybe you can find here on [regular-expressions.info/unicode.html](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html#prop) a property that fits your needs.

Another mistake in your expression is the `|` in the character class. Its not needed, you are just adding this character to your class and with it it will match words like `U|S|A`, so just remove it:

```
(?<![!?\.]\s)(\b[\p{Lu}][\p{Lu}\p{Ll}]+\b)+
```

Comment: Wow, thanks for the quick and amazing help! The only problem now is that the initial capitalized letter at the start of every line is matched. The idea behind only avoiding ?.! was to make sure I found everything except capitalized word in the beginning of a sentence.

Comment: The problem with sentences beginning with a name, could that be solved by looking for all the matches, so that if there are two sentences like this:
_My name is Mickey. Mickey is my name._
...the match in the first sentence would then locate the other exact matches, even if they were in the beginning of a sentence?

Comment: @BeeBeach I updated the solution now that it is not matching at the start of a row. I am sorry but I don't understand your second comment.

Comment: @BeeBeach thanks for jEdit. I downloaded it and I haven't seen an editor with such a great regular expression support, yet. I think I will use it more often.

Comment: Thanks, that update worked like a charm!
I'm going to use this to find instances of names of people and companies in a very large body of text, so they can be tagged. If a sentence begins with a name, then that name won't be tagged. Since a text is likely to mention that name in several places, could a second pass be made where all matches from the previous search could then be matched, even if they are placed as the first word of a sentence?

Comment: @BeeBeach I don't think you can do such a second pass with the search replace of a text editor. You could do that with a script where you build a list of the found names and then search if you find such a name without tags. But there could still be names that are only once and at the beginning of a row/sentence in your document.

Comment: When looking through a number of pages on RegEx, it looked like grouping with () and then referencing that with \1 or something similar would allow you to use the match as a "second input" of sorts. Perhaps I misunderstood that concept... P.S. If two or more consecutive words, separated only by a space or a newline, are capitalized such as **My company's called A Few Good Men** is there a way to have them show up as one match?

Comment: You forgot `\p{Lt}` for titlecase letters, `\p{upper}` for uppercase code points (whether letters or not!), and `\p{lower}` for lowercase code points (again, whether letters or not). That means you’ll screw up on strings like `"King Henry Ⅷ"` which has an uppercase number in it, and on `"I Work At Ⓚ"`, which has an uppercase symbol in it. I’ll spare you the titlecase examples. Also, there are plenty of letters that are not one of those, like the superscripts in 7ᵗʰ Heaven.  Those are `\p{Lm}`.  Maybe you should just use `\pL` or `\p{alpha}` or `\p{word}`.

Comment: @BeeBeach `(<Name>(.*?)<\\Name>.*?)(?<!<Name>)\2(?!<\\Name>)` replace with `$1<Name>$2<\\Name>` would work for a untagged name following in the same row, but not if the unttagged is before the tagged name and not when it is in another row.

Comment: Great work! Perhaps one could put in an exception for **I** and **A** ? I think I'll skip the idea of finding occurences in the beginning of sentences.